# OpenVPN fails while openssl verifies ok

Tags: openvpn, certificate-authority

I have recently created a new CA certificate, as the old one was about to expire. I deployed this certificate to our OpenVPN server, and on it the verification of local certificate goes ok with both certificates (sanitized):

```
# openssl verify -CAfile cacert.2009-11-19.pem server_cert.2012-12-05.pem
server_cert.2012-12-05.pem: OK
# openssl verify -CAfile cacert.2013-11-18.pem server_cert.2012-12-05.pem
server_cert.2012-12-05.pem: OK
```

But connecting to this server with OpenVPN gives me this on server's log (sanitized):

```
VERIFY ERROR: depth=0, error=unable to get local issuer certificate: /C=ES/ST=***/L=***/O=***/OU=***/CN=***/emailAdress=***
```

Any idea would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

OK, server certificate is fine. Did you try to verify client certificate:

```
   openssl verify -CAfile {path-to-yourCA.crt} {client.crt}
```

If it fails, re-generate client certificate. If client certificate is OK, try to increase openvpn log verbosity: `verb 6`, we need more information

Comment: Hi Selivanov Pavel. Client certificate also verifies OK with both CAcerts. I will try verb 6 once at the workstation, but I just created a new CAcert and new client and server certificates for critical systems and will create for all other clients afterwards. Thanks anyway.

Comment: My problem was the .crt did not include the root CA certificate. The example provided helped me notice and debug the problem was that one and not anything related to OpenVPN client/server. Thanks!